# Overwrite Value in Dataframe with checking Line before

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data, trend

So the DataFrame is:

```
1 28.3  
2 27.9  
3 22.4  
4 18.1  
5 15.5  
6 7.1  
7 5.1   
8 12.0   
9 15.1  
10 10.1
```

Now i want to replace all over 25 with `HSE` and all below with `LSE`. Everthing else is `"Middle"`. But i want to know if it was over 25 or below 8, before it got "Middle". So if it was over 25 before I would replace the value with "fHtM" and if it was below 8 before I would replace the value with "fLtM".

Thank you in advance.

Desired output:

Maybe like that:

```
1 S4  
2 S4  
3 S4  
4 dS3 (down to class S3)  
5 dS3  
6 dS2  
7 dS1  
8 uS2 (up to class S2)  
9 uS3  
10 dS2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [-np.inf, 6, 13, 19, np.inf]
labels=['S1','S2','S3','S4']
df['label'] = pd.cut(df['value'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
    a  value label
0   1   28.3    S4
1   2   27.9    S4
2   3   22.4    S4
3   4   18.1    S3
4   5   15.5    S3
5   6    7.1    S2
6   7    5.1    S1
7   8   12.0    S2
8   9   15.1    S3
9  10   10.1    S2
```

And if need add trend, use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

Explaining:

First get from column `label` second characters by `str[1]`, convert it to `int` number and count [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html). If duplicates, you get `0`, so need replace them by `NaN` and forward fill by `ffill()`.

```
dif = (df.label.str[1].astype(int).diff().replace(0,np.nan).ffill())
print (dif)
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3   -1.0
4   -1.0
5   -1.0
6   -1.0
7    1.0
8    1.0
9   -1.0
Name: label, dtype: float64
```

Then use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for creating `u` where value is `1`, `d` where is `-1` and empty string if something else what is added to column `label`.

```
df['label1'] = dif.where(dif.isnull(), np.where(dif == 1.0, 'u','d')).fillna('') + df.label.astype(str)

print (df)
    a  value label
0   1   28.3    S4
1   2   27.9    S4
2   3   22.4    S4
3   4   18.1   dS3
4   5   15.5   dS3
5   6    7.1   dS2
6   7    5.1   dS1
7   8   12.0   uS2
8   9   15.1   uS3
9  10   10.1   dS2
```

Comment: Thank you thats the same like i had it before. But if i want to make 4 classes like s1, s2, s3, s4 and i want to know if s3 (lets say 15-18) was before below 15 or over 18. so i can't use isnull.

Comment: Can you add desired output to question?

Comment: See below for desired output

Comment: Thank you. and what are values of classes s1, s2, s3, s4? s3 is 15-18, what about s1, s2 and s4?

Comment: thats just an example maybe: s1 <6, s2: 6 - 13, s3: 13 - 19, s4: >19  that would fit with the output posted

Comment: Ok, I think i understand. Do you need create categories by classes only?

Comment: I add new solution, please check it.

Comment: Yes that's what I have. But now i want to check what was before. I want to seperate the categories like S3 to dS3 and uS3 like posted. So that I know the value moved from the lower class to the S3 class or from the upper class to S3.

Comment: Yes,  but in `5 dS3` isnt typo - `5 S3` , because no change a row before?

Comment: Yeah you are right, but for the ongoing work it has to be dS3 till the next change.

Comment: It was no easy, please check my solution.

Comment: That would it be but i just get en error:  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'T'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119010/discussion-between-jezrael-and-madddin).